# Adicionar um delay na animação Buzz Out após cada loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, react

Olá, estou tentando colocar um delay em minha animação do Buzz out após cada loop, estou aplicando ela em um texto, que esta dentro da tag p. Já busquei varias respostas e a maioria delas diz para colocar a primeira porcentagem em 33%, para que ocorra um delay, eu entendi o conceito, mas parece que ele não se aplica ao meu problema.

Meu código html

```
<div className={style.container}>
      <div className={style.divImage}>
        <img src={image} alt="" className={style.image} />
      </div>
      <p onClick={onClick} className={style.text}>
        {text}
      </p>
    </div>
```

Meu codigo css

```
.text {
  font-family: RobotoCondensedBold;

  color: #7c7c7c;
  font-size: 22px;
  animation: text 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* @-webkit-keyframes text {
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
    transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
    transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
  }
} */
@keyframes text {
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
    transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
    transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
  }
}
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.text:hover,
.text:focus,
.text:active {
  -webkit-animation-name: text;
  animation-name: text;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Se alguém puder me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado eu serei muito grato, Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pedro, me parece que vc não entendeu muito bem o conceito, seja lá onde vc leu, então vou te explicar que ai vc pode ajustar como quiser.

Repare que a sua animação tem 1s e está dividida em 10 intervalos de 10%, totalizando 100%, ok. Para facilitar eu coloquei um "delay" na sua animação de 50%, ou seja. De 0% a 50% a sua animação fica parada, como a animação tem `1s`, ela vai ficar parada `500ms` antes de repetir o loop. E de 50% até 100% eu dividi novamente em um intervalo de 10 steps, agora ficando 50%, 55%, 60%, 65%, etc, até 100%.

Outro ex: com essa mesma animação se vc mudar para `2s`, ela vai fica `1s parada` e `1s animada`, pois o que importa e a divisão do `@keyframes` ao longo do tempo de execução.

O detalhe é que agora a animação que ocorria em `1s` agora ocorre em `500ms`, e vai parecer que está mais acelerada, mas ajustando os valores vc consegue deixar ao seu gosto, então vou deixar essa parte para vc resolver caso queira.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.text {
font-family: RobotoCondensedBold;

color: #7c7c7c;
font-size: 22px;
animation: text 1s linear infinite;
/* animation-delay: 1s; */
cursor: pointer;
}

/* @-webkit-keyframes text {
10% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
}
20% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
}
30% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
}
40% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
}
50% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
}
60% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
}
70% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
}
80% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
}
90% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
  transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
}
100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
  transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
}
} */
@keyframes text {
0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotate(0);
  transform: translateX(0) rotate(0);
}
50% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotate(0);
  transform: translateX(0) rotate(0);
}
55% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
}
60% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
}
65% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
}
70% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
}
75% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
}
80% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
}
85% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
}
90% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
}
95% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
  transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0);
}
100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
  transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
}
}
.text {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.text:hover,
.text:focus,
.text:active {
-webkit-animation-name: text;
animation-name: text;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<div className={style.container}>
  <div className={style.divImage}>
    <img src={image} alt="" className={style.image} />
  </div>
  <p class="text">
    {text}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu não estou muito familiarizado com o conceito de animação usando apenas css, acabei me confundindo ao tentar entender, agradeço pela explicação muito bem detalhada, gostaria de pedir se vc n teria alguma material para me indicar a respeito disso, pretendo entender mais sobre esses conceitos de animações. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Cara no YouTube mesmo vc encontra algum material, mas tb indico a doc da Mozilla, mas o principal e vc treinar, tentar replicar animações e testar as propriedade para ir vendo o que acontece etc...